# Passing an Empty/Null Date variable in VBA to an SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have an excel userform with various textboxes, some are fields to enter dates. The user can then save their entries.

At this point, I connect to an access backend via an ADO connection. The values entered by a user are passes to an SQL string, e.g.

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblDECONVERSION_DATA SET tblDECONVERSION_DATA.Status = '" & NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_CaseStatus & "', " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.DMS = '" & NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_DMS & "', " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.DateRecieved = #" & Format(NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_DateRecieved, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#, " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.WireDate = #" & Format(NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_WireDate, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "#, " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.LastEditXID = '" & CurrUser & "', tblDECONVERSION_DATA.LastEditDate = #" & Now & "# " & _
        "WHERE (((tblDECONVERSION_DATA.CaseID)=" & ID & "));"

        adoRecSet.Open Source:=strSQL, ActiveConnection:=dbconnect, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

However, some of the date fields can be left blank, meaning for example the NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_DateRecieved variable being empty. This causes a syntax error. How can I pass a Null or Empty date variable in the SQL statement that both VBA and the access database will accept?

Comment: If a date is left blank then you need to set the field to "null", but you cannot do that wrapped in `#`.  I would create a funtion (e.g. "DateOrNull") which checks the date input and returns the appropriate SQL.

Comment: Do you have situations where there is a date and you're updating it to NULL? If not, you could simply not update that field.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you for your advice. My actual SQL statement is very long and can contain up to 10 date variables. Is there a way to have one large SQL string and pass either null, if the date field is Null or Empty. Or the variable containing the date if the user has input one? E.g. If IsDate(LastLogInTime) Then sqlVar = "#" & LastLogInTime & "#" Else sqlVar = "Null". then pass sqlVar into the SQL string?
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTestDates SET tblTestDates.TestDate2 = " & sqlVar & " " & _
         "WHERE (((tblTestDates.CaseID)=" & ID & "));"

Comment: Difficult to suggest something concrete here without a bit more info: can you answer Dick's question?

Comment: @DickKusleika No, I wouldnt be updating an existing date to Null at any point. But the user can access the form and update the record as date values become available to them.Id have no way of knowing if/when they would want to update a specific field.So I wanted to update the record with all values on the userform each time the user updates their case, so that no matter which userform field theyve entered data on, itll be sent to the database record.
So if theyve entered a date, its variable will be wrapped in #, but if they havent entered a date in that field, its variable will just be "Null"

Comment: @TimWilliams Would breaking down the SQL string work in any way?
e.g.
strSQL = "UPDATE table SET table.field1 = '" & Var1 & "' "
If IsDate(TextBoxValue) Then strSQL = strSQL & "table.field2 = #" & TextBoxValue & "# " Else "Rest of SQL statement here..." So if the textbox value did contain a date value it would be included in the SQL string, but skipped if its value was not a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strSQL = "UPDATE tblDECONVERSION_DATA SET tblDECONVERSION_DATA.Status = '" & _
          NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_CaseStatus & "', " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.DMS = '" & NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_DMS & "', " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.DateRecieved = " & _
           DateOrNull(NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_DateRecieved) & ", " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.WireDate = " & _
           DateOrNull(NewBusiness_WorkQueue.Decon_WireDate) & ", " & _
        "tblDECONVERSION_DATA.LastEditXID = '" & CurrUser & _
         "', tblDECONVERSION_DATA.LastEditDate = #" & Now & "# " & _
        "WHERE tblDECONVERSION_DATA.CaseID=" & ID & ";"
```

An example function:

```
Function DateOrNull(v) As String
    Dim rv as String
    If IsDate(v) Then
        rv = " #" & Format(v, "mm/dd/yyyy") & "# "
    Else
        rv = " null "
    End If
    DateOrNull = rv
End Function
```

Comment: This won't work if you're using ADOBC parameters, and it's not recommended anyway as it's opening up for SQL Injection.